# How to change a file extension on an iPad

Tags: ipad, automation, ipados, shortcuts-app, files.app

I’m just starting to use an iPad for work, and I often need to change file extensions. For example, I might need to rename `example.txt` to `example.md`.

It seems like the way to do this should be to long-tap something in the Files app and tap “Rename”, but this doesn’t work—the rename dialogue hides the file extension. I also tried to make the Siri Shortcut below, but when I ran it on some test files, nothing happened. (It asked for the new extension but didn’t rename anything.)

So: how can I change the extension of a file on an iPad?

(To be clear: I do not want to “save as” like done [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251375632?answerId=252677416022#252677416022).)

Thanks.

[image: screenshot of a Siri Shortcut]